# Clear unambiguous questions vs asking someone to prove their question should be asked

Tags: discussion, questions

Clear unambiguous questions vs asking someone to prove their question should be asked. Which are you looking for here?

The latter seems like a foolish errand (no I am not going to prove that, nor the difference between the two, nor why I should ask the question, nor list alternative questions I could ask about clarity... let alone what I am doing here).

If you cannot identify what is being asked or some of the the question is ambiguous, even if you don't understand the relevance of some parts of the question... then I understand the need to complain about clarity. But I often feel like I'm being asked to prove my sanity in order to ask a question, which is dispiriting and has really put me off using the site, which is a shame because it **should** work.

If I hadn't learnt by now that philosophy stackexchange is completely incapable of asking any questions that wikipedia hasn't already botched, I would be quite upset :-(

Comment: maybe you could link to a specific instance of the problem? but generally speaking — providing background context/motivation for the question can be really helpful in terms of giving answerers insight into the actual problem you’re facing in your study..

Comment: I don't have all day @JosephWeissman any amount of examples would be incomplete and would probably generate unhelpful answers

Comment: We cannot change something that is merely based on your feelings, though. Yes, some users could be more welcoming towards new thoughts and more constructive. Without naming them, we cannot keep them in check well. Also, it is generally on the user to ask questions that are intelligible to others and (more or less objectively) answerable. And asking a good question is much harder than answering it, that much is certain.

Comment: I am not asking questions "merely based on my feelings". How could anyone do that? Today I feel sad. Sorry, I think you're being unclear :p @PhilipKlöcking

Comment: "But I often feel like I'm being asked to prove my sanity in order to ask a question" <- that's my point of reference here, need more concrete information to work with mate 

Comment: ah right ok I get it @PhilipKlöcking